# Unable to send GET request to a url in android?

Tags: android, rest, http

I am currently new to android programming but I recently created a rest api using slim library that takes a GET request and adds it to the database it's parameters but I don't know how to send it inside android app.

here is my code:

```
Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try
        {
        URLConnection myURLConnection=null;
        URL myURL=null;
        String mainUrl="http://107.170.31.137/StudentApp/v1/garden/name2/user2/pass2";
            myURL = new URL(mainUrl);
            myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
            myURLConnection.connect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "in catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

I even added the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

still the app is not working. am i doing something wrong? please help. also, I want to change the GET parameters every time to the new variables I get from somewhere else how can i do that?

Comment: Consider using AsyncTask for better handling of url connections , rather then using it on main thread , you may face issues  .  more details here :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Android won't allow you to do networking stuff in main UI thread. Plz use Async Task or some other thread for netwrork connection.

Comment: At the moment you have no parameters in your GET request. There is no query string.

Comment: networking on android  must be done on a background thread like AsyncTask or AsynctaskLoader.
http://guides.codepath.com/android/sending-and-managing-network-requests

Comment: @Vikrant okay. how can I use it? can you help me with that? like with my url. would be really helpful.

Comment: general attempt would be passing variables from url `http://someurl.com/mypage.php?varone=valueone&vartwo=valuetwo`  and using `$_GET['varone']` & `$_GET['vartwo']` to get the values in php . You have to figure out for slim library . Would you specify which are the variables and there respective values ?

Comment: in slim i can pass variables by adding slash at the end and they would be considered as parameters so after garden in the url it's the parameters to be added.

Comment: Why do parameters start after garden? And not before or with? How can i know the starting point?

Comment: You should first try your url in a browser on your device or pc. It does not work from here.

Answer (score 0):

For Network Relational Operations Make Use of the following Libraries(Asyntask)

1. **Retrofit** (Recommended)
2. **Okhttp**
3. **Volley**

Check my Example Project on [Retrofit](https://github.com/gotoark/RetrofitDemo)